# Probability problem about the rain

Tags: probability, statistics

How do I solve this probability question?

let's say there are 3 totally independent weather forecast websites. They use totally different ways to predict the weahter. 
Website 1 says: there's a 55% chance it's gonna rain,
Website 2 says: there's a 60% chance it's gonna rain,
Website 3 says: there's a 65% chance it's gonna rain.

What would be a correct estimate of the total probability it will rain? You could argue it's 60% because that's the average, but intuitively that sounds wrong to me. Because for example if 1000 websites claim there's a 60% chance it's gonna rain, isn't that prediction more valuable than if 1 website would claim that? What am I missing here?

Comment: Well, yes, if 1,000 websites reported the $60\%$ chance it'd make more sense. But they didn't - you just have the three websites to work with. It'd make sense in general to take an average over all of the websites you have the data for.

Comment: And in the case of the 1000 websites claiming it's 60%, what would the answer be then? Would you just multiply the chance of every website being wrong? So 0.40 * 0.40 * 0.40 ... ?

Comment: I don't think this really makes sense.  How can they be independent?  If we imagine that there is a true "probability of rain tomorrow" then all three ought to be correlated to that, hence not independent.   So, there is some dependence.  What sort?  Well, we have no idea.  If we had a history of the three predictions (and what actually followed) one could say more.

Comment: Well, assuming they all somehow used a different method, and ergo each being wrong was independent, yeah, I guess you're right - the probability would just be "1 minus the product of each chance of them being wrong".

Comment: The predictions are (hopefully) *not* independent. You *hope* that each of the websites predicted weather is positively correlated with tomorrows actual weather

Comment: Thank you, so you can't actually know the exact probability because there is dependance, but is there any way you can make an estimate prediction?

Comment: It would help to know the track record for accuracy of the three web sites. Most TV newscasts over-predict rain: (a) more interesting to talk about rain, (b) listeners are more forgiving about false alarms than about getting wet unexpectedly. // Coin toss is a better predictor than my local newspaper's 'forecast'.

Comment: Okay so let's take another example than the rain. Let's say I'm on the stock market and I have 2 indicators, one says there's a 55% chance the price will go up, one says there's a 65% chance it would go up. The accuracy of both indicators is the same. What would the answer then be?